# Magento 2: Display price from and to next to product listing

Tags: magento2, theme

Can anyone tell me how to make it so when you have a product with multiple prices inside such as configurable products it shows the price range on the product listings rather than just the lowest price?

I noticed that it does it [on this Magento 2 demo](http://magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/gear.html) right at the bottom for the Yoga kit. Yet when I have a product with different size options and hence different prices it only ever shows the lowest price in the listings and you don't see the different prices until you click through to the product... I am using Magento 2.0.2 presume this is a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think the issue is that the yoga kit is not a configurable product. It is a bundle product which has the limitation of allowing only simple products to be bundled.